# How to build a searchable database?

Tags: database, search, command-line

I would like to create (or use, if one already exists) a command-line based app that creates, modifies and searches a database.

This database would ideally be a simple text file where each line is an entry.

As in this simple example:

```
Apple    Fruit    Malus              Green/Red      55
Banana   Fruit    Musa acuminata     Yellow         68
Carrot   Veget.   D. carota          Orange         35
```

Let's say this text is stored in `~/database.txt`

I'd like to be able to search for all entries that are of the type `fruit` (returning, `Apple` and `Banana`) or all entries that have kilocalories that are less than `60` (returning `Apple` and `Carrot`) on the command line.

The returns  should happen through standard terminal output and should look like this:

```
$mydatabasesearch cal '<60'

Apple    Fruit    Malus              Green/Red      55
Carrot   Veget.   D. carota          Orange         35
```

Also, being able to add to the database through the command line would be awesome!

Is there anything around that does this? If not, how would you recommend I write such an app? I know a bit of `C++` but that's it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It is a bit more complex than plain text files, but a lot more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Plain text files are not really considered databases.

If you want to stick to textfiles and the commandline, have a look at the usual unix utilities like `grep`, `awk`, and the coreutils package (`cat`, `cut`, `uniq`,...) which work on plaintext files. Add those commands to a shellscript and you're done.

As soon as you move to some sort of database system you won't have textfiles as storage anymore.

Aside the already mentioned sqlite, the [Berkeley DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) library might also be worth a look if you want to write your own program. Both libraries should be good in your case since they don't require an external database server (like mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Unix anyway with a delimited file SED and maybe some simple commandline perl which you can wrap in a bash script.  There is a good tutorial for the data manipulation at [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ad_Hoc_Data_Analysis_From_The_Unix_Command_Line) and the SED you could use is probably all [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/) and in the part two tutorial.